# Why do these reactions occur?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

> Identify the products $[A]$ to $[D]$:
>
> $\ce{CH3COONa}+\ce{NaNH2} + \triangle \rightarrow [A]$
>
> $[A] +\ce{CO_2} \rightarrow [B]$
>
> $[B] + \ce{H2O} \rightarrow [C]$
>
> $[C] +\ce{P2O5 } \rightarrow [D]$
>
> $[A],[B],[C],[D]$ are the main product in each step.

According to my book's answer

$[A]=\ce{NaCH2COONa}$

$[B]=\ce{NaOOC-COONa}$

$[C]= \ce{(CH2COOH)}_2$

$[D]= \ce{C_3O_2}$

I can intuitively understand that product $[A]$ is correct.However I never learnt the next three reactions.Can someone explain/give a source from which I can learn why the next three reactions occur ?

Thanks.

Comment: You wrote B and C wrong.

Comment: That implies that the author of the study material wrote it wrong. BTW according to you what should be the answer? @Mithoron

Comment: B, C, and D should all have three carbon atoms. Your B has two, and your C has four.

Comment: @aventurin Bad reasoning.The equations may not be balanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstraction of $\ce{H+}$ by strong base $\ce{NH2^-}$
$$\ce{CH3-COO- + NH2^- -> ^-CH2-COO- + NH3}$$

Carboxylation to form malonate
$$\ce{^-CH2-COO- + CO2 -> ^-OOC-CH2-COO-}$$

Free malonic acid
$$\ce{^-OOC-CH2-COO- + 2 H+ -> HOOC-CH2-COOH}$$

Dehydration of malonic acid with $\ce{P4O10}$ yields carbon suboxide (unbalanced)
$$\ce{HOOC-CH2-COOH + P4O10-> O=C=C=C=O + H3PO4}$$